# PostgreSQL Query in Java won't sort using Order By

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm making a database query to a PostgreSQL server using Java and the corresponding JDBC driver.

The Query is:

```
select starttime, duration from callhistory3 where is_answ = 't' and callerid NOT IN ('PlayFile', 'anonymous') and NOT (char_length(callerid) = 3 AND char_length(dialednumber) = 3) ORDER BY starttime
```

Unfortunately the ResultSet is **not** sorted by starttime.

Example ResultSet:

```
2014-05-29 19:19:08,00:06:21.629
2014-05-29 19:52:19,00:00:02.71
2014-05-29 09:33:51,00:00:09.822
2014-05-29 10:38:52,00:00:03.026
2014-05-29 07:16:24,00:00:24.686
2014-05-29 07:35:58,00:00:55.013
```

If I use the same query in pgAdmin III, the result **is** sorted correctly.

Any idea how to get a sorted ResultSet without processing it in Java after the fact?  Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Post the relevant part of your Java code.

Comment: What datatype is the column `starttime`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The datatype for `starttime` is `timestamp without time zone`